# make account.invoice form 'no editable' when invoice state is 'paid'

Tags: button, hide, odoo, edit

i try to make account.invoice form 'no editable' when invoice state is 'paid'.
This is my code in acount.invoice class:

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False,submenu=False):
        result=super(account_invoice, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id, view_type, context, toolbar, submenu)
        if(view_type=='form'):
            invoice=self.pool.get('account.invoice')
            active_id=context.get('active_id',False)
            current_state=invoice.browse(cr,uid,active_id).state
            if current_state=="paid":
                result['arch']='''<form string="Invoice" edit="false" ....................></form>'''
        return result
```

but it looks like context.get('active_id',False) always return "false".

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the XML for the fields you don't want people to edit and give it an attribute like this:

```
<field name="your_field" attrs="{'readonly':[('state','in','paid')]}"/>
```

Or you can inherit the write method from the model and insert a check to see the current state and raise an exception.

EDIT:
You can hide/remove the buttons by editing the form

```
<form string="NAMEOFFORM" create="false" edit="false" version="7.0"></form>
```

Comment: when i say "no editable" form i mean hide or disable "edit button".

Comment: hey thanks for ur answer. thats correct but it will hide edit button from every account.invoice forms. I trying to hide edit button only if invoice state is "paid".

Comment: @leibstandarte Can you try combing the last part with the attrs from the first part?

Comment: i did it doesnt work: <attribute name="edit" attrs="{'invisible:[('state','=','paid')]'}"/>
            <attribute name="edit" attrs="{'invisible:[('state','=','paid')]'}">false</field>

            <attribute name="edit" attrs="{'invisible:[('state','=','paid')]'}">true</field>